# MS Reporting Service MHTML subscription suddenly truncated and in plain text

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

The report looks fine in reporting manager but the email is in plain text and is truncated.
At first I thought is was to do patching on the server but I have checked and it does not seem to be the case.

Comment: it also works fine if the format is changed to anything else than mhtml.

Comment: Have you tried dropping and recreating the subscription?

Comment: @R. Richards The subscription is dynamically generated on the fly per email. I found something on technet about a "." killing the email on the smtp server. I will try to test that today.

Comment: testing this right now 
https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/796360/reporting-services-subscription-rendering-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the bug (active) on technet
https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/796360/reporting-services-subscription-rendering-error

One of the fields presented in a table cell returned a single "." and that breaks the email/mhtml.

```
case col1 when '.' then '-' else col1 end
```

fixed it.

For this column. I don't see a solution for the complete report.